# OpenCV - cv2 video capture quality

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to setup a simple camera to record robotics, but I am struggling to get a good quality video feed. The link is to a picture comparing the video feed from OpenCV vs. the Windows 10 Camera app.

[Picture: OpenCV vs. Windows Camera Video Feed Quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jeqz4.jpg)

To my knowledge, I am keeping the same aspect ratio and resolution as the windows camera app but the quality seems very off and some of the picture seems to be cut off. This is the code I am using, and you can see 3 lines where I attempted to use different filters to get a better image quality (none of which worked):

`# cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 60)`

`# frame = cv2.detailEnhance(frame, sigma_s=10, sigma_r=0.15)`

`# frame = cv2.edgePreservingFilter(frame, flags=cv2.RECURS_FILTER)`

Code:

```py
def turn_on_camera():
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S")

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    width = 1920 # 300
    height = 1080 # 300

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter("C:\\Users\\Tecan\\Desktop\\Videos\\" + 'Tecan_'+today+'.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (width, height))

    while (True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (1920, 1080))
        out.write(frame)  # write frames of vidout function
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `cv.resize` interpolates. did you think that would make information appear that wasn't there before? or those detailEnhance/edgePreservingFilter stuff? those are futile. you need to set CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH and height. default is 640x480, which you are probably getting.

Comment: I didn't realize it interpolates, this solved my problem! Thank you very much.

Comment: to be sure you understand... _NOTHING_ can add information that you've already discarded (by not requesting the desired/maximum resolution from the camera).  cv.resize is not to blame.